# Unable to show maps in jquery.geocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocomplete

I am using [jquery.geocomplete.js](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete) for getting autocomplete search when searching for an address. The app is a ruby on rails app and here is what I have done:

1. Added 
   `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"> to the layouts before the addition of application.js`
2. Geocomplete javascript to the app
3. Added

   ```
   ready = ->
     $('#geocomplete').geocomplete(map: "#map_canvas")

   $(document).ready ready
   $(document).on "page:load", ready
   ```
4. SLIM:

   ```
   h1 Welcome

   form
     input#geocomplete type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90"
     input#find type="button" value="find"

   #map_canvas
   ```

Autocomplete options works without any problem but map is not showing up. How do I get the map to show here?

Comment: try to add height attribute for #map_canvas ie. #map_canvas{:style => "height:250px;"}, may be map is loading but can't see it

Comment: Oh yeah that is the solution. I had to set the height for the map. Can't beleive that I missed this out. Add that as an answer I will accept it. @chaitanyasaraf

Comment: :-) sometime i miss that too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add height attribute to div "map_canvas" to view map.
eg.

```
 #map_canvas{:style => "height:250px;"}
```